# Create javascript object with (number, number)

Tags: javascript

Sorry guys, I'm new to this and I have no clue how to do it!

I'm getting back geocordinates from an address I use. They are coming in as:

```
(1234.56, 123.456789)
```

I am using them to send to a database and I would like to send them as part of a JSON object like:

```
{
    address: addressInput.value,
    lat: //variable I store the lat in,
    lng: //variable I store the lng in
}
```

I assume I would need a function to take apart the numbers and store them into variables, but I'm not sure how to do that. Thanks!

Comment: Are you familiar with [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)?

Comment: is `(1234.56, 123.456789)` an actual string that is being returned, or are you using it as an example of an returned array?

Comment: @JesseKernaghan I would assume a string, because `()` are not valid in object syntax, or array syntax.

Comment: `'(1234.56, 123.456789)'.match(/\((.+),\s(.+)\)/)`

Comment: @MikeC I am not actually, I'll have to take a look into it!

Comment: @SterlingArcher I wasn't sure, I thought perhaps they might have mistakenly used `( )` to signify an example dataset rather than `[ ]`.

Comment: *"getting geocordinates from address site"* ....  Highly unlikely they are in format shown

Comment: In addition to `split`, you may be interested in `replace` and/or `substring` as well.

Comment: @charlietfl they are in a JSON format and they are from google. But when I try going through the JSON, it only lets me get both in the form above or it shows "undefined"

Comment: If o=(79.54,35.23) that is an array, use  **var s=o.toString();** then  **var coords=s.split(',');** coords[0] will contain 79.54 coords[1] will contain 35.23

Comment: google provides specific properties for latitude and longitude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
function createJSON(value){
    var lat_lng = value.toString().replace('(', '').replace(')', '').split(',');
    return {'address': addressInput.value, 'lat': lat_lng[0], 'lng': lat_lng[1]};
}

createJSON((1234.56, 123.456789));
```

Comment: I added an alert inside the function (to just check what the values it was returning were) it when I alerted lat_lng[0] it displayed the second number and when I alerted lat_lng[1] it said undefined

Comment: What is the value you are passing to the createJSON function?

Comment: the same you have in createJSON((1234.56, 123.456789))

Comment: Try passing it as a string. Like this `createJSON("(1234.56, 123.456789)")`

Comment: Passing it as a string worked!

Comment: If you pass the arguments as (1234.56, 123.456789) you are using the comma operator, which will evaluate to simply 123.456789. You'll want to wrap this in strings to prevent that.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this should do what you are looking for..

```
var data="(1234.56, 123.456789)";
data=data.replace('(','');
data=data.replace(')','');
var object = {
    address: "somevalue",
    lat: 0,
    lng: 0
};
var coords = data.split(',');
object.lat = coords[0];
object.lng = coords[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best solution :

```
lat = (str.split('(')[1].split(',')[0]).trim();
lng = (str.split('(')[1].split(',')[1].replace(')',' ')).trim()
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zb983wmp/

Answer (score 0):

```
var coordinates = '(1234.56, 123.456789)'.match(/(-?\d+.\d+)/);
var latitude = coordinates[0];
var longitude = coordinates[1];


{
  address: addressInput.value,
  lat: latitude,
  lng: longitude
}
```

A simple regex can grab the numbers for you. You can leave them as a string or parse them to a number, depending on what your backend is expecting.